# i want to inspect span class element using Selenium using other Selenium attributes than Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium

Please enter your password

i want to get the message "Please enter your password"

Is there any other attribute than Xpath?

The code appears like this:

```
<span class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" data-for="password" role="alert"><span class="k-icon k-warning"> </span> Please enter your password</span>
```

Thanks

Comment: The code appears like this:<span class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" data-for="password" role="alert"><span class="k-icon k-warning"> </span> Please enter your password</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

```
String d =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[data-for=password]")).getText();
System.out.println(d);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

can u try folloiwng one:
      WebElement ele=  driver.findElement(By.className("k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg"));
String text=ele.getText();
System.out.println(text);
   Try it